# Unity of a subring of $\mathbb Z_{10}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I've been told that $S=${$[0],[2],[4],[6],[8]$} is a subring of $\mathbb Z_{10}$ with unity $[6]$.

How is it true though?

$[2][6]=[12]=[2]$,
$[4][6]=[24]=[4]$, and so on, isn't it?

I realize I'm making a conceptual mistake somewhere. Can somebody please point it out to me?

Comment: I think that this is correct.

Comment: The calculations you do are consistent with $[6]$ being a multiplicative identity, and indeed it is - I'm not sure where you think you're making a mistake!

Comment: I'm sorry, I got confused! I thought I was supposed to get [1] on the RHS!

Comment: In this case.. $[6]$ *is* $1$. *Plays music from the twilight zone*.